# Ajax and PHP Sessions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, persistent

I have a template based site that relies on persistent sessions throughout. Recently I needed to expand the session storage by defining the save handler for database storage. This works fine in the general scope of the classes within the framework however when any of the pages make an ajax request the session id get regenerated and if the form gets submitted the previous session is gone.

```
  <?php

 require_once('site-database.php');
 require_once('site-config.php');


 class FileSessionHandler

 {


 private $database;

 private $life_time;


 public function FileSessionHandler(){


 $this->life_time = get_cfg_var("session.gc_maxlifetime");

 $this->database = new database();

 $this->database->newConnection(db_host,db_user_name,db_user_pass,db_user_database);


 session_set_save_handler(
array(&$this,'open'),
array(&$this,'close'),
array(&$this,'read'),
array(&$this,'write'),
array(&$this,'destroy'),
array(&$this,'gc')
);
```

}

Comment: your script - which ouhtit ajax request separate file or embedded in the structure, you may have forgotten session_start()

Comment: The handler class is called from the index page and the ajax pages. session_start is called after the handler is set on each page. The session is not maintaining persistence though and regenerates the id every time session_start is called making it impossible to pass the sessions from the ajax and hold on to them in the main classes.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you are handling the sessions?

Comment: require_once('site-sessions.php');
$handler = new FileSessionHandler();
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
session_start();

That is how the session class is called in the framework and ajax. I would prefer the id to be persistent and only regenerate when it is expired or browser is closed. When it was file based that it worked fine and kept the same ID.

Comment: just edited post with the class constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I altered a few variables within the php.ini file to see if something in there was causing an issue and now it works as well in the database as it did file based. Keeping the same ID.

session.cookie_secure  was set to 1 in the .ini file and I changed that to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Please check whether you have started the session with session_start().